# HTML full page zoom depending on screen resolution

Tags: javascript, html, css, zooming

I have a problem with displaying my `html` site on different monitors/resolutions. I was trying to to solve this problem with the following script, but it isn't working. How could I improve this?

```js
if (width <= 1280 && height <= 720) {
  document.getElementById('html').style.zoom = '50%';
```

```css
html {
 zoom: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could scale the content without javascript, just using a mediaquery and a `CSS3` transformation applied to the `html` element

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1280px) and (max-height: 720px) {
   html {
      transform: scale(.5);   
      // or simply zoom: 50%
   }
}
```

as a side note your code can't work because you're looking for an element with `id="html"`, while you're trying to target the `html` element (that is `document.documentElement` or `document.querySelector('html')`)

Answer (score -1):

I believe this is more of a viewport and/or css media query issue. You shouldn't be trying to fix your pages look with javascript because it can be disabled. I would suggestion reading up on viewports [Viewport Overview](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag). The most commonly used paired tags are:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Those will help with resizing most of the content on the page based on the device width, other changes you'll have to manage more manually via css media queries, here is an example:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    body {
        width: 80%;
        font-size: 15px;
    }
}
```

The above corresponds to, at 300px or smaller change the width and font size.

I hope this helps!